# Which equality comparator to use when database stores boolean values as 0 or 1 bit values

Tags: javascript

My database table stores true and false as a `bit` value which can either be null, 0 or 1.

In JavaScript I am using code like `if (dbobject.status == true)` which throws up a linting error that `===` should be used. If I use `===` then `1 === true` will fail because they are not the same type.

So am I supposed to:

1. Do `if (dbobject.status === 1)` instead which reflects the data in the database.
2. Or stick to `if (dboject.status == true)` and ignore the linting errors?

I suppose the question is: should Javascript code give priority to `===` over `==`?

Comment: Use `if (dbobject.status)` without an explicit comparison. The `true` value will evaluate to `true`, and `undefined`, `null`, and `false` will be `false`.

Comment: Explicit comparisons to `true` and `false` are *usually* a code smell.

Answer (score 2):

Most linting tools will mark a double equal operator as an error. This is because it performs implicit conversions.

#### Example

```
var status = 1;
var result = true;
console.log(status == result); // it prints out true.
```

The '==' *attempts* to convert one or both operands into comparable types. In this case: *1* becomes *true* and then the comparison continues. see [this MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

```
var status = 1;
var result = true;
console.log(status === result); // it prints out false.
```

The *'==='* will **NOT** operate that conversion. Therefore, it simply compares a *number* to a *boolean* and assumes that variables with different types contain different values.

Implicit conversion is perhaps good if you know what you're doing as it allows you to write things like:

```
console.log(123 == "123") // Implicit conversion, prints true;
```

Instead of:

```
console.log(123 == Number("123")) // Explicit conversion required, prints true;
```

Which can come in handy when the second value comes from a database that sends back numeric values as strings.

To avoid confusion and unintended conversions though, a strict equality operator ('===') is ***almost always*** preferred, as it states clearly the code intent:

```
if(status == true) // Forgot a '=' perhaps? is status a number, a boolean or a string?
if(status === 1) // Alright I got it now, status is a number.
if(status) // I see, status value is not important as long as it's *truthy* (not 0, undefined or null)
```

So, *`status === 1`* is most likely the best choice in your case it allows you to extend your code for handling the null or 0 cases separately if needed.

**OR**, you really know what you're doing and you're certain other devs will understand your code with a == so you go ahead and suppress the warning on that line or simply remove that rule.